# If any match found in the stream set data to innerobject of the first object in a list

Tags: java, list, java-8, stream

GroupNode Class:

```
@Data
public class GroupNode {
    private String groupName;
    private List<PolicyNode> policies;
    private String eventId;
}
```

PolicyNode Class:

```
@Data
public class PolicyNode {
    private String policyName;
    private String eventTime;
    private String eventId;
}
```

Here i want is if eventId of groupNode matches with the eventId of policyNode then i want to set the policyNode details in groupNode.

the code i've tried.

```
List<GroupNode> groupWithPolicy = groupWithoutPolicy.stream()
    .filter(gwp->groupPolicyNodeList.stream().anyMatch(gwop->gwop.getEventId().equals(gwp.getEventId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I know that i'm not setting any property here but I'm not getting any idea how to set those properties to a group node:/

this is the sample response i want:

```
"groups": [
            {
                "groupName": "My group",
                "policies": [
                    {
                        "policyName": "Inno-Test-Cust-Man-Policy",
                        "eventId": "67e3426e-fd42-483f-9d90-8f7d15646f6a",
                    },
                    {
                        "policyName": "Inno-Test-Cust-Man-Policy",
                        "eventId": "67e3426e-fd42-483f-9d90-8f7d15646f6a",
                    }
                ],
                "eventId": "2d72752d-8f28-4549-9c0c-986ac98873cf"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I removed lot of data from above output here the eventId's are not matching. so i've all groups list without policies attached to it. and all policies list. now based on eventId i want to add policies to the group.

Comment: What do you mean by "set the policyNode details in groupNode"? Can you show some sample input and outputs?

Comment: groupPolicyNodeList contains list of all group policies without groupName, groupWithoutPolicy contains all groups. ->groupName and eventId and policies as null ,so based on eventId i want to find the specific policies. and set that object to groupNode which is in groupWithoutPolicy

Comment: @Sweeper please check the edited comment

Comment: Shouldn't the `eventId` of the policies and group match in your output? Should they either be `2d72752d..` or `67e3426e..`?

Comment: EventId id group must match eventId of policy. In that output I'm getting wrong. That thing I want to solve. @user7

Comment: Thanks Dmitrii B and Alex Rudenko. I'll check and vote your code snippets. Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for example so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<GroupNode> groupWithPolicy = groupWithoutPolicy.stream()
            .map(s -> setPolicyNodeList(s, externalPolicyList))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}

private static GroupNode setPolicyNodeList(GroupNode groupNode, List<PolicyNode> policyNodeList) {
    groupNode.setPolicyNode (
            policyNodeList.stream()
            .filter(s-> s.getEventId.equals(groupNode.getEventId))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );

    return groupNode;
}
```

it's easy to read and understanding.

Also, you can do grouping and escape from O(n*n):

```
    Map<String, List<PolicyNode>> collect = policyNodeList.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(s -> s.getEventId));
    List<GroupNode> groupWithPolicy = groupWithoutPolicy.stream()
            .peek(s -> s.setPolicies(collect.get(s.getEventId())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to update *existing* groups without policies, which can be done as follows:

```java
List<PolicyNode> policies = buildPolicyList(); // aka groupNodePolicyList
List<GroupNode> groups = buildInitialGroupList(); // aka groupWithoutPolicy

groups.forEach(group ->
     group.setPolicies(
         policies.stream()
                 .filter(p -> group.getEventId().equals(p.getEventId()))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList())
));
```

Ater that, the groups with empty policy list can be filtered out:

```java
List<GroupNode> groupsWithoutPolicy = groups
        .stream()
        .filter(g -> g.getPolicies().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Another approach could be to prepare a map of `<String, List<PolicyNode>>` from `policies` to reuse it as a cache when setting the policy list in group nodes:

```java
Map<String, List<PolicyNode>> mapEventPolicy = policies
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Policy::getEventId));
```

Then the list of groups with policies may be built by filtering and re-collecting without affecting initial list of groups:

```java
List<GroupNode> groupsWithPolicy = groups
        .stream()
        .filter(group -> mapEventPolicy.containsKey(group.getEventId()))
        .map(group -> new GroupNode( // use/add appropriate all-args constructor
            group.getGroupName(), 
            new ArrayList<>(mapEventPolicy.get(group.getEventId())),
            group.getEventId()
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: a copy of policy list should be provided per group.